# Visual Studio Blue Debug and Run button has disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code, button, interface, settings, visual-studio-debugging

The "debug and run" button which is located in blue box has disappeared in my visual studio code. I couldn't found any solutions for this problem. I know that I have another choice to run the visual studio. But I used to launch this program with that button but using it with the other run button seems different. By saying "different" I mean they both have different interfaces in terminal. Can anyone help me about how can i bring it back?

I tried resetting all the menus, resetting open user settings(JSON), resetting view locations, updating the vs code, but it made no sense(btw im using linux mint for developing).

Also by saying "blue button", what i mean is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfr7O.png)

Comment: 1) visual studio and VS Code are completely different things. fix your terminology 2) _what_ blue run button? where? from what extension?

Comment: I have edited my post and added a link to image of the button to declare what I mean. Its not coming from any extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw I noticed that my problem has solved automatically by itself. I don't know how. I'm closing the topic. Thanks for everyone who had thought on this topic to find a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).